# PyQt4: Graphics View and Pixmap Size

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, qgraphicsview, qpixmap

I'm developing a GUI using QTDesigner for some image processing tasks. I have two graphic views beneath each other in a grid layout. Both should display an image and later on I will add overlays.

I create my Pixmap *img_pixmap* and add it to my Scene. This scene is then added to my graphics view. Since my image is much larger than my screen size I apply *fitInView()*. In code:

```
self.img_pixmap_p =  self.img_scene.addPixmap(img_pixmap)
self.img_view.setScene(self.img_scene)
self.img_scene.setSceneRect(QtCore.QRectF())
self.img_view.fitInView(self.img_scene.sceneRect(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
```

So far, so good but how do i get rid of the white space around my image view? Ideally, I want my pixmap use the full width of the graphics view and to keep the aspect ratio, the graphics view should adjust its height accordingly. Any ideas on how to achieve that in a straight forward fashion?

Here an image to get a better idea of what I get:

[image: Nobody likes white borders]

As you can see, there are white borders, which I want to avoid.

Comment: `QGraphicsView` can't adjust its size according to the scene's size by default. You need to calculate optimal height manually and set it using `view.setFixedHeight(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I did as suggested by Pavel:

```
img_aspect_ratio =  float(pixmap.size().width()) / pixmap.size().height() 
width = img_view.size().width()
img_view.setFixedHeight( width / img_aspect_ratio )
img_view.fitInView(img_scene.sceneRect(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
```

It works fine when you call this in each `resizeEvent()`.