# Adjust GraphicView according to any image geometry

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview

My QGraphicsView should show an image of a large resolution. The size should fit inside a resizable window. Currently, the image is viewed in a way that I want it to but only by providing some manually adjusted values to the initial view geometry. This doe not look neat. I also tried to refer to the solutions posted here: [Graphics View and Pixmap Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30951727/pyqt4-graphics-view-and-pixmap-size)

My current Window looks like this:

[image]

```
class ImageCheck(Ui_ImageCheck.Ui_MainWindow, QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ImageCheck, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Image Analyzer")

        self.crop_ratio_w = 1
        self.crop_ratio_h = 1

        self.path = None
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.scene.clear()
        self.image_item = QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        # This is the approximate shift in coordinates of my initial view from the window
        self.view.setGeometry(self.geometry().x()+ 10, self.geometry().y()+ 39, 
                    self.geometry().width()- 55, self.geometry().height()- 110)

        self.view.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.view.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)

        def setImage(self, path):
           self.path = path
           self.crop_ratio_w = self.pixmap.width() / self.view.width()
           self.crop_ratio_h = self.pixmap.height() / self.view.height()

           pixmap = QPixmap(path)
           smaller_pixmap = pixmap.scaled(self.view.width(), self.view.height(),
                    Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, t.FastTransformation)

           self.image_item.setPixmap(smaller_pixmap)
           self.scene.addItem(self.image_item)

           self.scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, self.view.width(), self.view.height())
           self.view.setGeometry(0, 0, self.view.width(), self.view.height())   

           self.view.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
           self.view.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
           self.view.setScene(self.scene)
           self.view.setSceneSize()

        def resizeEvent(self, event):
           self.view.setGeometry(self.geometry().x()+ 10, self.geometry().y()+ 39, 
                    self.geometry().width()- 55, self.geometry().height()- 110)
           self.setImage(self.path)
```

My manual override was probably not a good idea when I tried to determine distances between two points. Even the scaled distance gives me a slightly wrong value.

Comment: You could share your high resolution image to test your code and thus be able to help you

Comment: I have uploaded one such image here: https://imgur.com/SAMPtCX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not use your code because there are many hidden things so I will propose the next solution that is to rescale the view based on the scene each time the window changes its size. I have also implemented a signal that transports the clicked information in the image based on the coordinates of the image.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class ClickableGraphicsView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QPoint)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ClickableGraphicsView, self).__init__(parent)
        scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.setScene(scene)
        self.pixmap_item = None

    def setImage(self, path):
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(path)
        self.pixmap_item = self.scene().addPixmap(pixmap)
        self.pixmap_item.setShapeMode(
            QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem.BoundingRectShape
        )

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self.pixmap_item is not None:
            if self.pixmap_item == self.itemAt(event.pos()):
                sp = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
                lp = self.pixmap_item.mapToItem(self.pixmap_item, sp)
                p = lp.toPoint()
                if self.pixmap_item.pixmap().rect().contains(p):
                    self.clicked.emit(p)
        super(ClickableGraphicsView, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.fitInView(self.sceneRect(), QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio)
        super(ClickableGraphicsView, self).resizeEvent(event)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Image Analyzer")
        view = ClickableGraphicsView()
        view.clicked.connect(print)
        view.setImage("image.jpg")

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Distance")
        display = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber()

        buttonbox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(
            QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel
        )

        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        lay = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(widget)
        lay.addWidget(view, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        hlay.addWidget(label)
        hlay.addWidget(display)
        hlay.addStretch()
        lay.addLayout(hlay, 1, 0)
        lay.addWidget(buttonbox, 1, 1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I tried to fit the scene following your suggestion into my code but it does not work there somehow. Since the original code posted is just a function, I have uploaded the full code here: https://pastebin.com/1A6QW7Ew

Comment: can you please try to see if the error in my image resizing can be solved by applying your solution in this format? You can double click on the path of the files to view my image window.

Comment: @abk A simple question: Does my code generate what you want?

Comment: Unfortunately, It does not work in my class with the windows generated using my code

Comment: @abk I think you have not understood me, have you tried my code? If you have tried it and it is what you want then I will implement it in your code.

Comment: Sorry that I misunderstood. Yes, it works exactly the way I want.

Comment: @abk In the following is the code with all the features that your code had: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/02ed3111c96bcdc93b46f08e62632546

Comment: Thank You and yes this works very nicely (and looks easier too). I think the overuse of UI files generated using Qt_Designer was bad idea in my original code.